# Stream вернуть значение из листа после flatMap

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть лист Car в котором содержится еще один лист Door, нужно найти подходящую машину с определенной дверью, стримом делаю flatMap двери и фильтрую по условиям для двери.

```
    List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream()
            .map(Car::doors)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(codeParam))
            .filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(codeParam))// Другие условия
            .filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(codeParam))// Другие условия
            .max(this::compareDoors)
            .orElse(null);//вот здесь хотелось бы вернуть Car, но вернуть можно только Door
```

Можно еще один стрим добавить где будет уже фильтроваться по содержания элемента Door в Car.doors или обойтись без map и flatmap доабвить длинное условие в filter в котором будет опять еще один стрим.

Но можно ли вернуть Car без дополнительного стрима или как то используя библитеку StreamEx(не нашел в библиотеке способа для этого)?

Comment: Пытался использовать collect groupingby который возвращал бы Pair, но и это не получается с groupingBy

Comment: Вынесите предикат для фильтрации в отдельный метод, который будет принимать на вход `Car`.

Comment: Да, так тоже можно, но хотелось бы чтобы было так же читабельно, фильтр и комаратор в одном месте. Но к тому же как оказалось такой вариант не работает. потому что comparator будет работать только внутри каждого Car, а нужно чтобы всех Car всех Door

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно во Stream.flatMap передать свою реализацию создания стрима, и возвращать Stream. Можно так же в этой же реализации flatMapa добавить фильтрации.

```
 List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
 lsit.stream()
     .flatMap(c -> c.getDoors().stream().map(d -> Pair.of(c, d)))
     .filter(p -> p.getValue().getCode().equals(codeParam))
     .max((p1, p2) -> ObjectUtils.compare(p1.getValue().length(), p2.getValue().length()))
     .map(Pair::getKey)
     .orElse(null);
```